# How do I pass Date in PathParam

Tags: date, types, jpql

Query:

```
public List<Resident> findByDob(@PathParam("dob") Date dob {
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Resident.findByDob");
    query.setParameter("dob", dob);  
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

I don't know what to do, because date is not supported, how can I solve the problem? The language is JPQL.

Comment: Which language?

Comment: What's the content of named query `Resident.findByDob`?